# ODATA Filter for lists/libraries using TemplateFeatureId guid property

Tags: filter, odata, guid

24Hrs into learning about OData queries for a SP project that was dumped on me.

I can get the data i need from

```
_api/web/lists?$select=Title,TemplateFeatureId,Author&$expand=Author
```

But I tried to use a filter on the property TemplateFeatureId using the 'guid' value and it doesn't return anything.

```
_api/web/lists?$select=Title,TemplateFeatureId,Author&$filter=TemplateFeatureId eq '00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101'
```

(note: i dropped the expand Author thinking it was a part of th problem but not sure)

I have seen when using OData and GUID's you should not enclose the value in single quotes but SharePoint does not like this,

> The expression "TemplateFeatureId eq
> 00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101" is not valid

Yet using the single quotes i get no results I think it is because its comparing a string against an edm.guid type. Per above.... how can I handle this in the filter correctly?

Can someone help a noob out please...

Comment: What is the datatype of "TemplateFeatureId" column?

Comment: You might need to use `GetItems` & CAML (POST) call instead of `items`. Try GetItems example given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121444/how-to-get-the-id-of-a-list-item-with-a-given-guid-in-sharepoint-online-with-res). let me know if thos works for you

Comment: Divya its Edm.Guid
<d:TemplateFeatureId m:type="Edm.Guid">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d:TemplateFeatureId>

Ganesh, thanks i will take a look and see if it help for now i have been able to resolve another issue that has made this need less urgent and am about to take some holiday time.